# Preserving Node V8 Debugger Sessions Between Test Runs

Tags: node.js, debugging

Node has this great new feature where you can:

1. pass a `--inspect` option when you start Node
2. copy a URL that Node will then generate
3. paste that URL in to Chrome
4. debug using the Chrome debugger

That's fine for general debugging, but it makes test debugging somewhat painful.  Even if you use Node's `--debug-brk` option to pause the test execution while you do the copy/pasting, having to do it for every test cycle really slows things down.

Is there any way to use the V8 debugger that somehow keeps the debugger open in Chrome between test runs, or is there any way to make Chrome automatically "pick up" a new test run debugging session?

Comment: I think you can just reload in dev tools and the source will update if it changed on the fs

Comment: Right, but so ... imagine that I run the test suite once, and I get the URL "a", which I copy/paste in to Chrome.  Then I run the test suite a second time, generating URL "b".  The problem is, at that point it doesn't matter whether I reload the dev tools page in Chrome or not: Chrome is still on URL "a", with no awareness that I started a new test run ("b").